# web page crash in chrome when loading large json

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, memory-leaks, memory-profiling

I am working on a web application. Requirement is to load 60,000 record on the first page.
I am using `oboe library` to stream `JSON` of 20,000 records(right now we have `JSON` of 20K records only). As the `JSON` loads I process it.
But the page crashes in between the load of 4K-5K. records.

I tried loading just the `JSON` and not doing anything with the `JOSN`. That is I did not attach any handlers to the `oboe ajax` request. But still the page crashed. I profiled this case and found that 
`(GC Root)` occupies 703870536 Bytes and inside it `(Global handles)` occupies 703227252 Bytes. I am attaching the memory profiler screenshots(summary-view, containment-view, statistics-view) of this case.

I dont know how to free this memory and avoid crash. Please help. Thanks.

[image: Summary view]

[image: containment view]

[image: statistics view]

Comment: Do you manage to make this work fine? I'm facing the same issue using oboe in an AngularJS application

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly what you should change based on the information you have provided, but I'll try to give a general solution. Based on the information you provided it sounds like you might be trying to read in an insanely amount of json at one time.

If you changed to the source of the json to allow you to read a hundred records at a time, then update the page, and then ask for more records and do it again. You may solve your problem. Also be sure to set objects to null and get rid of the information you are storing on the heap in-between loading sets of records.

See this url for pagination of rest api's it gives a good idea for a possible implementation. https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-rest-api/pagination-in-the-rest-api